# Android Splashscreen mode is different from the application mode

Tags: android, splash-screen, darkmode, android-splashscreen

Hello I use the `androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.1` library to manage my splashscreen, but when I configure the dark/light mode in my application the splashscreen always keeps the system mode, except I want it to have the same mode as the application configuration .

sorry for my english and thank you for your help.

how to force the splashscreen to use the same mode as the application and not the system and for info the mode I save it in the sharedpreference